# DynamoDB generates multiple INSERT events for the same record

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, stream, amazon-dynamodb

There is a Lambda that processes INSERT events received from a DynamoDB table stream, the table has a single attribute HASH, let's say RecordId.

Now once a record is created and quickly after updated by PutItem command, it generates multiple INSERT events though the following events should UPDATE events.

BTW, if it could be related, the record have a 24-hour later ttl attribute.

Also, I cannot reproduce this, I am just concluding it based on the Lambda execution logs.

ANSWER:
figured it out, the record was deleted and re-created, I though it was just updated.

Comment: If the problem is resolved, then please close the question.

Comment: How can I close it?

Comment: Either add an appropriate answer and accept it, or simply delete the question (given that it was user error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the record was deleted and re-created, I though it was just updated.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB streams provides you exactly once delivery of an event, there are no duplicates. But, with that said you Lambda is free to retry an event twice which would show it twice in your execution logs. In essence, it's up to you to ensure your Lambda function is idempotent.

Comment: It is not Lambda as I can see the other fields in the record are changed in each round of processing in the Lambda.

Comment: My suspicious is DynamoDB streams misrepresent UPDATE event as INSERT.

Comment: No that would not happen, and if it did I would be aware of the bug. You must have a downstream application also updating the item.